# Wrong width for empty part in multipart rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, multipart-node

The Tikz&Pgf manual says, on page 820:

> `/pgf/rectangle split empty part width=<length>`  (no default, initially 1ex)
>
> Sets the default width for a node part box if it is empty and empty parts are not ignored.

I can't understand what I'm missing to set the empty part to 0.5cm.

This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[margin = 5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    2p/.style = {
        draw, align = center, minimum height = 0.5cm,
        anchor = east,
        inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt,
        text width = 1cm,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
    }
]
    \draw[orange!30, very thin, step = 0.1cm] (-0.5, -1) grid (2.5, 3);
    \draw[blue!50!black, thin, step = 1cm] (-0.5, -1) grid (2.5, 3);
    
    \node[2p, rectangle split empty part width = 0.5cm] at (2, 2.5) {A};
    \node[2p, rectangle split empty part width = 0.3415cm] at (2, 1.5) {B};
    \node[2p] at (2, 0.5) {C};
    \node[2p, rectangle split empty part width = 0.1ex] at (2, -0.5) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

The results:

1. Node A is set to 0.5cm, but has a bit more than 0.65cm;
2. Node B is set to 0.3415cm (trial and error method) and it's empty part is almost 0.5cm;
3. Node C sets nothing, therefore using the initial value (1ex);
4. Node D is set to 1ex, but the width is not the same as in C.

I couldn't figure out how to manage to get 0.5cm for the empty `nodepart`. `inner sep` and `outer sep` are 0pt, `text width` seems to work well. Playing with different `line width`s doesn't help either.

I'm now stuck...

Maybe there are other settings I'm not aware of.

Comment: You need to add the `inner sep` to have a match. Or set the `inner sep` to `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately `inner sep` is already set to `0`.

Comment: `rectangle split` has some bugs in the current code (for the example a misuse of `outer sep`), maybe it's another one.